# In-App App Widget configuration

Tags: java, android, configuration, android-appwidget

How do I configure an **App Widget**, that was added to the home screen, not immediately (like a configuration activity), but afterward in the actual App (MainActivity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make IntentService that have logic for fetching data and fillings RemoteViews for your widget. So when user put your widget for the first time - just make in OnEnabled() an empty view with button that will triggering configuration activity. So now, you can update your widget everywhere from the app with IntentService and actions for them.